# Encrypting data transfer from one page to another

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, https, web

I have a website in ASP.NET.  When I run the website and use the developer tools in Google Chrome, I am able to observe the data that was inputted in the log-in page.  The data has been encrypted using MD5 hashing prior to being sent to the database.  How come I am still able to know what the user inputted from the developer tools in Google Chrome?

How can I make this data not visible when it is being sent from the browser?  Do I need to use HTTPS?  Thanks

Comment: *Do I need to use HTTPS? *  Yes.

Comment: Yes definitely. That is network traffic you are looking into.You need to use HTTPS for to encrypt that traffic.

Comment: "Encrypted" doesn't mix with "MD5". Chances are you have several form fields and you're hashing one into another but then submitting all of them. HTTPS? YES

Comment: I thought that they weren't related but I decided to mention them the same to be sure.  I am now trying to see how I can make use of HTTPS.  Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form data submitted over a non SSL connection can definitely be seen. Whether or not you're hashing this data before submission, if it's important, make sure it's all done in a SSL session.

Comment: Can you please guide me about how to create an SSL session in ASP.NET please?  The website I am talking about is on my IIS as well but I will not publish it on the web.  I will only use it for demonstration purposes, so I can't purchase a security certificate.

Comment: Sorry, I'm mostly an 'apache guy'. Search around bit, it's a super common topic. You're bound to find a decent guide. And if you still have problems getting that setup, ask separate question here or over on serverfault